# Inverter sequencia de id em um tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tive que migrar um site que foi feito em PHP puro para Wordpress, busquei na internet e conseguir copiar os dados da tabela do site antigo para a estrutura do Wordpress, que aconteceu uma coisa, todas as noticias foram copiadas de trás para frente, aí quando as noticias que estão exibindo primeiro são as mais velhas, então pelo o que eu entendi se eu consegui inverter a ordem os ID na tabela eu resolvo isso, pesquisei na internet e não achei nenhum exemplo, de como fazer um UPDATE em uma tabela com numero sequenciais.

No meu Banco tem um coluna chamada "ID" os registro comente de 1 e vai até 114
eu gostaria que esse ID tivesse os registro invertidos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
EX: 114,113,112.. até chegar ao número 1

Comment: dá uma amostra dos dados que você tem

Comment: Como eu faço isso?

Comment: coloca na pergunta alguns registros que você tem, e qual estrutura básica da tabela, e como deve ficar o resultado final

Comment: veja se consegue entender agora, fazendo um favor

Comment: qual a versão do banco ?

Comment: 5.7.19 essa é a versão do meu mysql

Comment: resolveu seu problema ? marque uma resposta por favor

Comment: nem testei, por dois motivos, primeiro que o cliente não viu problema nas notícias ficarem na ordem invertida,  e segundo porque como fiz no worpress e já tinha cadastrado várias imagens de destaque, ia gerar problema

Comment: ok, de qualquer forma ambas as repostas funcionam, vide sqlfiddle, então acharia adequado marcar a melhor (a do bacco) como resposta pra fechar a questão

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso, com isso poderá ajudar outras pessoas que passem por esse problema, obrigado cara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não acredito que inverter os IDs seja a melhor solução, mas como foi o que pediu, segue:

- Faça backup dos seus dados, caso tenha algum problema com os passos seguintes;
- verifique qual é o maior ID de todos da tabela desejada;
- multiplique este valor por 2, e some 1. Anote para uso na *query*.

  Ex: se o maior ID for 213, o valor final será 427 (afinal, 213 × 2 + 1 = 427).
- Execute uma única vez esta *query*, substituindo o 427 do exemplo pelo valor encontrado no passo anterior:

  ```
  UPDATE tabela SET id = 427 - id;
  ```

Pronto, você terá os IDs em ordem invertida. A única coisa que pode causar estranheza é que eles não vao começar de 1, mas isso não deve ser um problema para a finalidade desejada.

A razão de usarmos um valor maior é bem simples: Você não pode ter dois IDs repetidos, então o resultado cálculo acima forçosamente irá ser sempre maior que os existentes na tabela antes do `UPDATE`, garantindo que a execução não contenha um erro de índice repetido.

Se quiser realmente manter a numeração do 1 (desnecessário, mas em todo o caso...) pode fazer esta *query* depois da anterior (novamente, uma única vez):

```
UPDATE tabela SET id = id - 213
```

Desta vez, subtraindo o valor do maior ID obtido no começo dos passos.

<sub><sup>Usei valores diferentes para manter seu foco nos passos e não só na *query* final. Os valores no caso da pergunta são 229 e 114, respectivamente.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que está correto a forma que está... o problema de exibição pode ser causado por outro fator, configuração talvez. Se você inverter a sequência, o próximo post, seria o código 115 e estaria logo depois do "olá mundo" que foi o primeiro... recomendo não realizar esse procedimento sem antes verificar o que pode ser.

Mas, se atentando apenas a questão de inverter a numeração.

Você primeiro tem que mudar todos os números para um intervalo que não tenha conflitos. poderia fazer assim:

```
update tabela set id = id + 1000;
```

Feito isso, você faz um select, numerando as linhas por ordem de id decrescente e guardar ela em uma tabela temporária:

```
with temp as 
(
 select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.id desc) as i from tabela t order by t.id desc 
)
```

Por fim, você aplica o novo id no registro, como sendo o número da linha do select armazenado na tabela temporária:

```
update tabela set id = (select x.i from temp x where x.id = tabela.id );
```

> Foi utilizado o MySQL 8 como exemplo. A função row_number() só está disponível a partir desta versão.

---

Para outras versões, o seguinte código pode ser utilizado:

```
update tabela set id = id + 1000;

update tabela set id = (select x.i from (select t.*,  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS i from tabela t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r order by t.id desc ) x where x.id = tabela.id );
```

Coloquei no [**DBFiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iJtnJ4WJEASic68eVqxqNZ/0)

> A solução do Bacco está claramente mais simples e funcional para o caso em questão, mas como já tinha feito o código pra refazer a numeração, vou deixa-lo aqui também.